# Is Pippin the dog a reference to the original Jaws film?

Tags: reference, the-meg

In [*The Meg*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4779682/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt), there is a scene where a dog named Pippin is swimming in the waters near where a shark is swimming.

There was a scene in the original [*Jaws*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073195/?ref_=nv_sr_1) that included a dog named Pipit. Although you never see the death of Pipit in *Jaws*, it is presumed that he was killed by the shark.

Did filmmakers of *The Meg* include Pippin the dog as an homage to *Jaws*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [an interview with the film's makers](https://screenwritingmagazine.com/2018/08/13/the-meg-writers-on-meeting-and-dodging-expectations-of-a-summer-blockbuster/), there were a number of very deliberate 'nods' to Jaws, including the inclusion of this similarly named dog.

> *“When I first read the original material,” says Georgaris, I wasn’t worried about comparisons to Jaws, I was more thinking about Jurassic Park and being wary of that franchise and wanting to respectfully play in a different space. Yes, it’s a shark that happens to be huge but really what we’re talking about is a prehistoric monster that happens to be discovered in the ocean. The three of us have always talked about James Cameron movies like The Abyss and Steven Spielberg movies, so I think it was as much about trying to get all of the thrills and humor that you want in a movie that at it’s core is something that’s both really scary and really absurd.”*
>
> *“Obviously,” adds Jon Hoeber, “Jaws was a massive touchstone both
> culturally and for all the creative team. We didn’t want to redo it,
> but be respectfully aware of it and have fun with it.*
>
> *But they also weren’t afraid to get a little meta. **In The Meg, there’s
> a little dog named Pippet – the same name as the dog that appears in
> Jaws. The writers don’t take credit for the Easter egg, however, they
> say it was the director, Jon Turteltaub’s, idea.***
>
> <sub><sup>The Meg writers on meeting and dodging expectations of a summer blockbuster</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

## Probably.

The dog in Jaws is called [Pippet](http://jaws.wikia.com/wiki/Pippet_(Dog)), and the similarity seems much more than a coincidence for me. Pippin's fate is shown to the audience (and it's a good one, yay!), contrary to Pippet's.

It's also [not the only reference](https://www.theaustralian.com.au/arts/review/mad-meg-shark-movie-has-boxoffice-teeth/news-story/c8ea8d1209c6a1b72341896b42d692e5) to Jaws.

> The poster, for example, upsizes the Jaws one, and it was frightening enough.

[image]

Other references include [specific shots](https://www.looper.com/130947/the-ending-of-the-meg-explained/).

> The Meg even features many shots that seem to be direct references to the 1975 classic, as fans noted immediately upon the release of the trailer. It's hard not to remember the death of Alex Kintner during The Meg's climactic beach frenzy. Even Pippin the dog seems likely named after Jaws' Pippet (though unlike his predecessor, Pippin survives in a crowd-pleasing surprise reveal).

As far as I know, the producers have not commented on this, so we are bound to speculate. However, it does seem to be a discrete homage.